# Nested-if statements

Tags: matlab, if-statement

If I have this layout

```
if (condition)
  if (condition)
     do_something

  else
     do_something1

else
     do_something1
  end
end
```

Is there a way that when I get to the first else, that it runs do_something1 without me having to retype the code for do_something1? So I'd like to jump from the first else, to the second one

Comment: If it is just about retyping copy and paste works as well in Matlab ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can replace:

```
if (condition1)
  if (condition2)
     do_something
  else
     do_something1
else
     do_something1
  end
end
```

with:

```
if (condition1 & condition2)
     do_something
else
     do_something1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
if(condition && condition{
  doSth.
}else{
  doSth2
}
```

- `&&` is a "and" Java Operator look for "and" Operator for Matlab, there is one for sure.